# Docx (xml) file parsing error on Python 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 7618: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, lxml, decoding

im trying to parse docx file. I unziped it first, then tried to read Document.xml file with `with open(..)` and its raise error that "'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 7618: character maps to ". XML is "UTF-8" encoding:

[image]

Error:

[image]

I wrote the following code:

```
        with open(self.tempDir + self.CONFIG['main_xml']) as xml_file:
            self.dom_xml = etree.parse(xml_file)
```

I treid to force encode to UTF-8, but then i can't read `etree.fromstring(..)` correctly

7618 symbol (from error) is :
[image]

Please help me. How to read xml file correctly?
Thnks

Comment: Can you share this XML?

Comment: `with open(<name of xml file>, encoding='utf-8') as xml_file`

Comment: @Alderven, yes, sure, that link for .docx file from drive.google: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fvmyiJz0WMM-E-X3LP6Raw5B2-_Udw38/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @snakecharmerb , i treid to do this way, but as i told, xml_file becomes invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works without errors on your [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fvmyiJz0WMM-E-X3LP6Raw5B2-_Udw38/view?usp=sharing):

```
import zipfile
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

zipfile.ZipFile('file.docx').extractall()
root = ET.parse('word/document.xml').getroot()
```

Comment: Yes its work, but i dont understand why it crashes with using `lxml` and `with open()`. Anyway, thanks a lot )